# Limit access to local data and applications while accessing the desktop remotely

Tags: windows, group-policy, remote-desktop

We need to access client systems (desktops) remotely to do routine troubleshooting activities, however this isn't a very secure method to do as it exposes the local data to support personnel. Also, support has ADMIN credentials to log into the end user systems. Further users can't see what's happening on their system because the screen gets locked while it's being accessed remotely.

Is there a way via GPO we can request a couple of dedicated IDs from the client with limited rights and make that OU have restricted access to file shares, local drives, applications etc.?

I researched on Microsoft forums and this kind of seems possible, but wanted to confirm if anyone has implemented this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create limited users with Remote Desktop rights, and assign those users to your support personnel.  You can also use [Remote Assistance requests](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx) or use screen sharing apps like VNC, Intelliadmin, DameWare Utils and any of a dozen others I may have missed.

Comment: Thanks! Can't use any paid/freeware/shareware/opensource utilities as per contract. I'm aware of the Remote Assistance requests but doesn't that work in the same LAN?

Comment: @Chelesa Doesn't have to be, no.  Hell, if you ever get on a call with MS support, Remote Assistance is their preferred method of providing support, and that's certainly not only an option if you're on Microsoft's LAN.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for correcting me there. I got confused between Remote Assistance and organization's collaboration tool. I'll do a PoC of this between the 2 networks and I'm expecting it works!! Thanks again.